Is it possible to generate POJOs by graphql-maven-plugin?
It's a project where I have to deserialize graphql responses, so I have to get POJO classes from graphql schema. How I can generate ONLY POJO classes from graphql schema with maven using graphql-maven-plugin without server code or client code?
